# how to do a zoom in/out with wxpython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, zooming

how to do a zoom in/out with wxpython? what are the very basics for this purpose? I googled this, but could not find much, thanks!!

Comment: Your question is more likely to get answered if you add some more details (the more the better), for starters what exactly it is you want to zoom in on. However this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664109/general-zoom-algorithm-for-drawing-program may help

Comment: many many thanks to you, volting :)

Comment: @volting: I want to use the mouse to drag, then a rectangle would appear to embrace the area that I want to zoom in

Answer (score 2):

Instead of zoom, perhaps 'scaling' is what you're looking for:

http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Size-class.html#Scale

Answer (score 2):

You should look at FloatCanvas or FloatCanvas2. I know one of them has a zooming (and maybe panning) feature. You can get ideas about drawing rectangles from Whyteboard. Here's a few links:

http://wiki.wxpython.org/FloatCanvas
http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.floatcanvas-module.html
http://whyteboard.org/

Comment: thank you, but how am I gonna install it into my folder? I tried but failed... thanks ~~

Comment: You should be able to unzip FloatCanvas to your folder (if it's not already included with wxPython). Whyteboard is a program all by itself. I just recommend downloading the source and reading it.